# No FluentValidation.Mvc.MetadataExtensions in 3.4.6.0 (avoiding System.Security.VerificationException)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.5, fluentvalidation

I've inherited some code that uses FluentValidation 3.0.0.1 and on my machine that has .NET 4.5 installed I get the scary `System.Security.VerificationException : Operation could destabilize the runtime` error. After reading this post: http://elegantcode.com/2012/08/23/net-4-5-operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-yikes/ I updated FluentValidation and FluentValidation.MVC3 nuget packages to newest version 3.4.6.0.

But... after update, this code does not compile:

```
rules.RuleFor(x => x.Number).DisplayName("Bla bla bla"); // <-- No DisplayName method
```

It fails because it relays on `using FluentValidation.Mvc.MetadataExtensions` and this namespace does not exist in DLL instaled with 3.4.6.0

Is there some `MetadataExtensions` equivalent in newest FV? If not, how can I replace `DisplayName`, `Scaffold`, `HiddenInput` and similar methods with something that works in newest 3.4.6.0?

*(I'm completely new to FluentValidation - just stumbled upon it because of VerificationException)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation of the newest version was not an option but I've downloaded [3.0.0.1 source](https://github.com/thecodejunkie/FluentValidation/archive/3.0.0.1.zip) and applied [change](https://github.com/thecodejunkie/FluentValidation/commit/ddc1d7235b9c122c06fd224e8490b94791a715c0) to AbstractValidator class.

```
// Func<CascadeMode> cascadeMode = () => ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode; // Deleted
static Func<CascadeMode> s_cascadeMode = () => ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode; // Added
Func<CascadeMode> cascadeMode = s_cascadeMode; // Added
```

After replacing original 3.0.0.1 with patched version application starts without `VerificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using FluentValidation  new version, so you'll have to use WithMessage instead of display like this below

```
 RuleFor(x => x.city).NotNull().WithMessage("City is required");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got the news that updating FV to newer version will break some existing functionality. I will have to apply fix to 3.0.0.1 manually...